# How to get the following complex acyclic?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, proof-explanation

I have asked a question here:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251808/how-to-get-the-following-complex-acyclic. But there is no response. So I repost it here.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a triangulated category and $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{C}$ be a full triangulated subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$. We define

$\mathcal{U}^{\bot}=\{X \in \mathcal{C}| Hom(U,X)=0$ for all $U \in \mathcal{U} \}$.

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional k-algebra. $\mathcal{I}$ is the full subcategory of mod $A$ formed by injective modules. $K^b(_A \mathcal{I})$ is the bounded homotopy category of injetive modules. 
There is a proposition and its proof:

Propostion: If fin.dim(A) < $\infty$, then $K^b(_A\mathcal{I})^{\bot}$=0.

Proof: Assume that $K^b(_AI) \not=0.$ Let $I^{\bullet} \in K^b(_AI)^{\bot}$. We assume that $I^{\bullet}=(I^i,d^i_I)\not=0$. Applying the translation functor if necessary we may assume that $I^i=0$ for $i <0$. Next conside the complex $$ \cdots 0\rightarrow Hom(D(A_A),I^0)\rightarrow Hom(D(A_A),I^1)\rightarrow \cdots$$ Since $I^{\bullet} \in K^b(_A\mathcal{I})^{\bot}$, we infer that this complex is acyclic. Note that proj.dim cok $Hom(D(A_A),d^i)<\infty$. But this contradicts fin.dim$(A)<\infty$.

My question in the proof is that

1. how to use $I^{\bullet} \in K^b(_A\mathcal{I})^{\bot}$ get this complex is acyclic?
2. It says this contradicts fin.dim$(A)<\infty$, because for any n, there is an i suct that proj.dim $cok Hom(D(A_A),d^i)=n$. But wether there is a j such that $I^{k}=0$, for all $k>j$? Then $cok Hom(D(A_A),d^k)=0$, so it doesn't contradict with fin.dim$(A)<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The degree $k$ homology of $\textrm{Hom}\left(D(A_A),I^\bullet\right)$ is the space of homotopy classes of maps from $D(A_A)$, considered as a complex concentrated in degree $k$, to $I^\bullet$. Since $D(A_A)$ is in $K^b(_A\mathcal{I})$ and $I^\bullet$ is in $K^b(_A\mathcal{I})^\perp$, this must be zero for all $k$.
2. Since $D(A_A)$ contains every indecomposable injective as a direct summand, $\textrm{Hom}\left(D(A_A),I^k\right)=0$ if and only if $I^k=0$. But if $I^k=0$ for all $k>j$ then $I^\bullet$ is in $K^b(_A\mathcal{I})$. Since it's also in $K^b(_A\mathcal{I})^\perp$, it must be isomorphic to zero (since the identity map $I^\bullet\to I^\bullet$ is zero).

Comment: Do you mean each term in the complex $$ \cdots 0\rightarrow Hom(D(A_A),I^0)\rightarrow Hom(D(A_A),I^1)\rightarrow \cdots$$ is zero? Then $cokHom(D(A_A),d^i)=0$. How to get the contradiction with fin.dim$(A)< \infty$?

Comment: @Penson $I^k=0$ if and only if $\textrm{Hom}\left(D(A_A),I^k\right)=0$, since $I^k$ is in $\textrm{add}\left(D(A_A)\right)$. I'll edit to include this step.

Comment: Sorry, there is a place I don't understand:"The degree $k$ homology of $Hom(D(A_A),I^{\bullet})$ is the space of homotopy classed of maps from $D(A_A)$ to $I^{\bullet}$", could you tell me?

Comment: Oh, I get it. Do you mean this: $H^nHom^{\bullet}(X,Y)=Hom_{K(A)}(X,Y[n] )$, for $X,Y \in C(A)$?

Comment: @Penson Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JeremyRickard  In   your answer 2, how to get that $I^{\bullet} \in K^b(_A \mathcal{I})$?(the definition of $K^{b}(_A \mathcal{I})^{\bot}$ is in $K(A)$ or in $K(\mathcal{I})$? )

Comment: @Daisy I'm just saying that **if** $\textrm{Hom}\left(D(A_A),I^k\right)=0$ for all $k>j$ (which was the case Penson was worried about), then $I^k=0$ for all $k>j$, and so $I^\bullet\in K^b(_A\mathcal{I})$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I want to ask why $K^b(_A\mathcal{I})^{\bot}=\{ X \in K(\mathcal{I})|Hom(U,X)=0$ for all $U \in K^b(_A \mathcal{I}) \}$ not that $\{ X \in K(A)| Hom(U,X)=0$  for all $U \in K^b(_A \mathcal{I}) \}$ ?

Comment: @Daisy You'll have to ask Penson which category he's working in. But I was assuming he meant $I^\bullet$ to be a complex of injectives, since he used the notation $I$.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard. Thank you very much.